# How to make Eclipse search for JDK on another drive

Tags: java, eclipse, path

So I've been getting this error when trying to start Eclipse:

> "No java virtual env found after searching the follow locations:
>   /absolute/path/to/jre6/bin"

- I checked the control panel and I got JDK (Update 21 / 64-bit) installed.
- However, JDK is installed is installed on my primary drive (the sdd with Windows on) whereas Eclipse is unzipped and executed from my secondary hard drive.

How to I tell eclipse to find Java on my c-drive instead of the d-drive where it's located?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update. I relocated my Eclipse-folder to my C-drive where Java is "supposedly" installed and it still gives me the same error. 

Could it be something wrong with my Java installation? My Eclipse is a completely fresh install.

Comment: Update 2. I found an entry in the control panel for a Java (32-bits). But the version of java I installed recently was 64-bit? Could it have to do with the 64-bit version v.s the 32-bit version?

Comment: update 3. For whatever reason, typing "java - version" in CMD returns nothing,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you uninstall all versions of Java you have installed and then installed the one you want to use.

Another option is to tell eclipse which Java to use. For example: `eclipse -vm c:\path\to\jre\bin\javaw`

Answer (score 0):

Locate the eclipse.ini file and ensure that the variable -vm is correct (
[FAQ How do I run eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F)):

> If a JVM is installed in the eclipse/jre directory, Eclipse will use it; otherwise the launcher will consult the eclipse.ini file and the system path variable. Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable.